# Make icon hover in wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a ':hover' on a menu link in WordPress.

how do I make the :hover effect work for the "event" part as well, and not just the  icon?

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/b5stmnj0/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `.icon:hover` to `a:hover .icon`

See Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/oLpes7nh/

CSS:

```
a:hover .icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #e6e1d7;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Bpz.svg) no-repeat center;
  mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Bpz.svg) no-repeat center;
}
```